# EPS to PDF error using AucTeX

Tags: texlive, auctex, eps, ghostscript, texlive-2016

After updating TeX Live Utility (version 1.26) and some of the Emacs packages, my EPS to PDF conversion does not work any more when I do the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[outdir=./img/]{epstopdf}
\graphicspath{{img/}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [anchor=west, inner sep=5pt] at 
    (current page.west) {\includegraphics[height=6cm]{circle_fitted}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
%%% End:
```

Please note that I am specifying the flag "-shell-escape".

The error says:

```
ERROR: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./img/circle_fitted-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.

--- TeX said ---

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14 \end{frame}

--- HELP ---
No help available
```

The output of compilation is

```
Running `LaTeX' on `test' with ``pdflatex  -file-line-error   -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" test.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(./test.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasercs.sty)
Document Class: beamer 2015/01/05 3.36 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 8a39122e1f63)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasedecode.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/xxcolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaserequires.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecompatibility.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasefont.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sansmathaccent/sansmathaccent.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetranslator.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator-language-mappings.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetwoscreens.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoverlay.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetitle.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasesection.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframe.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseverbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframesize.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframecomponents.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenotes.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetoc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetemplates.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseboxes.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenavigation.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetheorems.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasethemes.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemedefault.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/font/beamerfontthemedefault.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/beamercolorthemedefault.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemedefault.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterthemedefault.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfpages.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
Package pgfplots: loading complementary arithmetics for your pgf version...

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststructure.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststructureext.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsarray.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsmatrix.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstableshared.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsdeque.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.data.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.verb.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstackedplots.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplotimage.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scaling.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.errorbars.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.markers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)))
(./test.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./test.out) (./test.out)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-basic-dictionary/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-bibliography-dictionary/translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-environment-dictionary/translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-months-dictionary/translator-months-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-numbers-dictionary/translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-theorem-dictionary/translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict)

Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} into your preamble.
 on input line 8.

(./test.nav)epstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 41577 2016-06-30 16:38:01Z karl $) 2.25
!!! Error: Cannot open Ghostscript for piped input: gs -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=./img/circle_fitted-eps-converted-to.pdf -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages#/None - -c quit
system returned with code 512


./test.tex:14: Package pdftex.def Error: File `./img/circle_fitted-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14 \end{frame}


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 14.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 1.0pt have occurred.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 14000 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.

TeX Output exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon Sep 12 19:31:38
```

**Update**

As David Carlisle mentioned in the comments, the problem is with the Ghostscript (gs). If I run `lualatex --jobname=main  -file-line-error   -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" main.tex` in the terminal everything works out fine. So the problem is with Emacs not being able to locate gs even after I insert the following in the `~/.emacs` file:

```
(setq preview-gs-command "/opt/local/bin/gs")
```

I took the path from the output of entering `which gs` in the terminal. Is there anyone who has a clue about what I can try to solve my problem?

Comment: you have shell-escape in the local variables in the buffer, but see the start of the log, pdftex was not started with `-shell-escape`, however epstopdf should run in restricted mode anyway so main error seems to be `!!! Error: Cannot open Ghostscript for piped input:` which appears to be a problem with `gs`

Comment: Which version of AUCTeX are you using?  `TeX-file-line-error` variable has been introduced in 11.89, if you're using a previous version setting it won't have any effect.  In addition, make sure you didn't customize `LaTeX-command-style` variable.

Comment: @giordano, I use 11.89.5. Absence of customisation of `LaTeX-command-style` had no effect. I still need to provide the path if I want it to work.

Comment: My comment was more about the fact, noted by David, that `TeX-file-line-error` has no effect.  In the output buffer, can you see now the `-file-line-error` option in the first line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that worked for me turned out to be the following:

1. Since I was able to compile from terminal, I suspected that there is smth wrong with the path to gs. I ran `which gs` in the internal shell which revealed that, indeed, Emacs does not see gs.
2. I added the following line to my `.emacs` file (the location of gs was obtained by running `which gs` in the terminal):

   `(setenv "PATH" (concat "/opt/local/bin/:" (getenv "PATH")))`

And it worked!

Comment: which Emacs do you use on your Mac OS X ? there is some hack needed for the GUI Emacs to inherit user environment. For example the https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport/releases has it out-of-the box.

Comment: @jfbu, I was using 24.5. Updated to 25.1, but I still need to add path to `gs` in order for Emacs to see it.

Comment: I see, but I meant which binary do you use ? do you compile from sources ?

Comment: Nope, the latest build from https://emacsformacosx.com/builds

Comment: I tried (finally) your mwe (with some random graphics in place of your `circle_fitted`) with the Emacs build I linked to in my first comment and using AucTeX 11.89.4, and I have no issue. hence it would be interesting if you could try it out, if it works with nothing added to your `.emacs` this would confirm it has to do with missing extra step to provide GUI Emacs with your shell env. But this might depend on the Mac OS X version. Mine is Mavericks.

Comment: and also I confirm I don't need the `--shell-escape` flag. (using pdflatex, not tested lualatex).

Answer (score 1):

There is a exec-path-from-shell available via https://melpa.org/ which possibly could be relevant to your problem.